# Is it possible to distribute a NWJS app as a single exe-file?

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I exported a game out of Construct 2 using their NWJS exporter. I need to distribute this game to a client who is not very technically adept to put it nicely. I think he would be able to run an exe-file by double-clicking it, but for example extracting a zip-file is probably too much to ask.

Is it possible to somehow distribute the result as a single executable file?

Here's what the folder that Construct made contains:

```
locales (folder)
d3dcompiler_47.dll
debug.log
dxwebsetup.exe
icudtl.dat
libEGL.dll
libEGLSv2.dll
natives_blob.bin
node.dll
nw.dll
nw.exe
nw_100_percent.pak
nw_200_percent.pak
nw_elf.dll
package.nw
resources.pak
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use [enigma virtual box](http://enigmaprotector.com/en/aboutvb.html) or something similar. It can pack app into standalone app.exe with all files, libraries, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [How to package and distribute your apps](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/how-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps) on the NW.js official wiki

There are a few methods there covering not only windows.